# Switch to next screen after Facebook auth

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing mobile app on Xamarin.Android, it uses Facebook authorization. After user authorized the Facebook auth screen does not disapeared at once. It stuck for some time and then moves back to start screen. However I need to move user to screen with main functionality.

```
// this is a method in MainActivity which shows user Facebook auth screen,
// and then calls callback function from shared assembly where is all GUI
private async Task Authenticate(Action<MobileServiceUser> actionOnComplete)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _client.LoginAsync(this, 
    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook).ConfigureAwait(false);

            actionOnComplete(user);
        }
        catch {
        }
    }

    // Here is a implementation of callback function 'acitionOnComplete'
    // in shared Xamarin assembly
    void OnFacebookLoggedIn(MobileServiceUser user)
    {
        // This code doesn't switches to PhoneEnterScreen at all.
        // Possibly because Facebook screen is still there              
        Navigation.PushAsync (new PhoneEnterScreen ());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised to make this more of an answer!

You should be listening for changes to the Facebook Access token, and using that to prompt your UI to push the main screen. I suspect your implementation is getting hung up somewhere.

You should likely do the following:

- Subclass FacebookTokenTracker and have it notify whichever service when the access token has changed.
- Have THAT service check to see if the updated token is valid (is a non-null/empty string), and if so push your main screen.